# In R, how can I generate a subgraph from a igraph object based on multiple attribute scores?

Tags: r, attributes, social-networking, igraph

I have a `igraph` object with 3000 vertices and 4000 edges. Both vertices and edges hold attributes.

One of the vertex attributes is `city` and has a valid input for all vertices.

I want to select all vertices that live in the top 10 most common cities and create a new graph for these. I know what these top 10 cities are.

When I do so for a single city, it works fine:

```
new_graph<-induced.subgraph(old_graph, which(V(old_graph$city=="LOS ANGELES")
```

However, I do want to include 9 more cities into the `new_graph`.

Can I simple extent my `which` argument here? Or should I write a `loop`?

Does anyone has some ideas? Any help will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You can specify more cities with `old_graph$city %in% c("LOS ANGELES","BOSTON","KALAMAZOO")`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks again, MrFlick! If I run the following, it indeed selects both Los Angeles and San Jose inventors. Stupid, but I never thought to structure the argument like that. Thanks again.

`new_graph<-induced.subgraph(old_graph, which(V(old_graph)$city %in% c("LOS ANGELES", "SAN JOSE")))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than testing for equality, you can use the `%in%` operator to match any value in a list. Just use

```
new_graph<-induced.subgraph(old_graph, 
  which(V(old_graph)$city %in% c("LOS ANGELES","BOSTON","KALAMAZOO")))
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe somewhat more readable, you can avoid the `which`:

```
new_graph <- induced.subgraph(old_graph, 
  V(old_graph)[ city %in% c("LOS ANGELES", "BOSTON", "KALAMAZOO") ])
```